# Calculate draws faster in VB.Net

Tags: performance, algorithm, vb.net

I created this calculation algorithm, unfortunately, it works a little hard for more combinations. How should it be improved for faster operation?

```
  Private Sub BttRemize_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BttRemize.Click
        If CBRealTime.Checked = True Then
            Dim myProcess As System.Diagnostics.Process = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess()
            myProcess.PriorityClass = System.Diagnostics.ProcessPriorityClass.RealTime
        ElseIf CBHigh.Checked = True Then
            Dim myProcess As System.Diagnostics.Process = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess()
            myProcess.PriorityClass = System.Diagnostics.ProcessPriorityClass.High
        ElseIf CBAboveNormal.Checked = True Then
            Dim myProcess As System.Diagnostics.Process = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess()
            myProcess.PriorityClass = System.Diagnostics.ProcessPriorityClass.AboveNormal
        ElseIf CBBelowNormal.Checked = True Then
            Dim myProcess As System.Diagnostics.Process = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess()
            myProcess.PriorityClass = System.Diagnostics.ProcessPriorityClass.BelowNormal
        ElseIf CBNormal.Checked = True Then
            Dim myProcess As System.Diagnostics.Process = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess()
            myProcess.PriorityClass = System.Diagnostics.ProcessPriorityClass.Normal
        ElseIf CBIdle.Checked = True Then
            Dim myProcess As System.Diagnostics.Process = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess()
            myProcess.PriorityClass = System.Diagnostics.ProcessPriorityClass.Idle
        End If
        TxtMReadOnly.Clear()
        For i As Integer = 1 To 10
            Try
                If TxtListScanValue.Text = 1 Then
                    TxtDrawR1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine & lastDraw1)
                End If
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: As the title states and the content shows, this is VB.Net code. Could you please change the tag to reflect that? VBA and VB.Net are different languages.

Comment: sorry for mistake,I changed now with Algorithm, i don't work change with vb, i don't have reputation point.

Comment: Welcome to code review! In the question can you please tell us what you mean by `it works a little hard for more combinations` and explain what is being calculated a little better so that we can understand the question better?

Comment: should improve this code, display results faster. Do you think something can be done, or did I make the most of it?

Comment: Why did you remove a large portion of the code?

Answer (score 2):

The question indeed deserves clarification. That being said...

Do you realize that by having an empty `catch` you are silently swallowing exceptions that may occur, thus making your code hard to debug ? Either remove all those `catch` or add some code that actually handles the exception. One catch for the whole procedure should suffice anyway.

As for this loop:

```
For i As Integer = 1 To 10
    Try
        Dim txtRemove As TextBox = CType(Me.Controls("txtDrawR" & i.ToString), TextBox)
        txtRemove.Clear()
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
Next
```

It could be expressed like this (a simple loop on the form's child controls):

```
    For Each ctl As Control In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf ctl Is TextBox Then
            ' optionally
            If ctl.Name.StartsWith("txtDrawR") Then
                DirectCast(ctl, TextBox).Clear()
            End If
        End If
    Next
```

This is more flexible and will work regardless of how many `txtDrawR` textboxes there are in your form (even if there is none).

The `case` statement can surely be simplified by a loop, list or something similar.

Progress bar Value and Maximum should be integer values eg. `ProgressBar1.Value = 0` instead of: `ProgressBar1.Value = ("0")`. Likewise: `ProgressBar1.Maximum = Convert.ToInt32(TxtCheckL.Text)` instead of: `ProgressBar1.Maximum = TxtCheckL.Text`
*provided that you have validated TxtCheckL contains digits only* or an exception will occur. Instead of a textbox you could use a [spinner](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/numericupdown-control-overview-windows-forms) or a similar control that will directly return an integer value based on user selection and requires less validation.

This is pretty bad:

```
Dim tmp(10000) As String
```

Rather than working with large arrays you can instead use a `StringBuilder`, or perhaps a `List (Of String)`. But it's not clear to me why you are even doing this, why you have 10000 (how was that value chosen ?) lines to put in `TxtMReadOnly`, and then split the string. It doesn't look good in terms of performance.

Note that if you want to iterate lines in a multi-line textbox you can simply do:

```
For Each s As String In Me.TextBox1.Lines  
     ' do something
     console.writeline(s)
Next
```

No need to do splitting once more.

There is a lot that can be improved, but if you could explain the general purpose we may be able to help further.